# Changing the ACL on a PFObject does not persist to the Parse Server

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, pfobject

When I save a change to the `ACL` on a `PFObject` (in this case, making it publicly writeable), the completion block runs successfully but the change is not actually saved to the server. Re-fetching the object, or viewing it via Parse Dashboard, shows that the `ACL` change is not persisted. In fact, I have verified via server logging that Parse server never even receives a request.

```
// first fetch an object from the parse server, then...
print("before: \(object.acl?.hasPublicWriteAccess)") // "false"
object.acl?.hasPublicWriteAccess = true
object.saveInBackground { (success, error) in
    // confirm that success is true and error is nil
    print("after: \(object.acl?.hasPublicWriteAccess)") // "true" - object is updated client-side

    // now, re-fetch the same object or check it in Parse Dashboard. It is not saved as publicly editable.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When changing an object's `ACL`, the object itself is not marked as 'dirty', so saving it does not result in a request to the server. You can verify this by checking the `isDirty` property on the object after changing the `ACL`.

This is in common with other `PFObject`s - a change to a pointer property does not mark the parent object as dirty. This is not normally encountered since it is natural to simply save the pointer object itself. Since there is no `PFACL.save()` function, we can instead re-set the `acl` property on the object to ensure that it is marked as dirty:

```
object.acl?.hasPublicWriteAccess = toggle.isOn
object.acl = object.acl
object.saveEventually()
```

Additional discussion of this can be found in [this issue](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/1328).